# Initialize Objects like arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

In PHP, you can initialize arrays with values quickly using the following notation:

```
$array = array("name" => "member 1", array("name" => "member 1.1") ) ....
```

is there any way to do this for STDClass objects?
I don't know any shorter way than the dreary

```
$object = new STDClass();
$object->member1 = "hello, I'm 1";
$object->member1->member1 = "hello, I'm 1.1";
$object->member2 = "hello, I'm 2";
```

Comment: you should change the "correct tick" from Tim to the answer of Dumbo

Comment: @mrzmyr, dumbo or gumbo?

Comment: @Pacerier sorry, i meant Gumbo :)

Comment: I tend to make a static `::fromArray(...)` method which can instantiate and return new instances, or arrays of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a ([post](https://web.archive.org/web/20100109111521/https://www.richardcastera.com/2009/07/06/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass/)) showing both type casting and using a recursive function to convert single and multi-dimensional arrays to a standard object:

```
<?php
function arrayToObject($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }
  
    $object = new stdClass();
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
            $name = strtolower(trim($name));
            if (!empty($name)) {
                $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Essentially you construct a function that accepts an `$array` and iterates over all its keys and values. It assigns the values to class properties using the keys.

If a value is an array, you call the function again (recursively), and assign its output as the value.

The example function above does exactly that; however, the logic is probably ordered a bit differently than you'd naturally think about the process.

Comment: I asked for multi-dimensional arrays, so this is it. Thanks.

Comment: For the moment, I will work with type casting only. On the long run, I will go for a mix between gnud's and this answer: A dumb_container object that can work recursively. Thanks all.

Comment: Can you expand this answer to here? The link could've been dead.

Comment: The Link is in fact dead!

Answer (score 56):

You can use type casting:

```
$object = (object) array("name" => "member 1", array("name" => "member 1.1") );
```

Comment: While I'd personally suggest actually making your classes do something, and using arrays as "dumb containers", this is the way to do it.

Comment: Jani, you have a point, but I just *love* addressing containers the -> way. :)

Comment: Cheers, I didn't know it was that easy - at least for one-dimensional ones.

Comment: @Gumbo, This wouldn't work above 1D. Simplest solution is to write our own function that expands it.

Comment: This should probably also have `(object)` before the *second* `array`. See @nickl-'s answer.

Answer (score 31):

I also up-voted Gumbo as the preferred solution but what he suggested is not exactly what was asked, which may lead to some confusion as to why `member1o` looks more like a `member1a`.

To ensure this is clear now, the two ways (now 3 ways since 5.4) to produce the same `stdClass` in php.

1. As per the question's long or manual approach:

   ```
   $object = new stdClass;
   $object->member1 = "hello, I'm 1";
   $object->member1o = new stdClass;
   $object->member1o->member1 = "hello, I'm 1o.1";
   $object->member2 = "hello, I'm 2";
   ```
2. The shorter or single line version (expanded here for clarity) to cast an object from an array, ala Gumbo's suggestion.

   ```
   $object = (object)array(
        'member1' => "hello, I'm 1",
        'member1o' => (object)array(
            'member1' => "hello, I'm 1o.1",
        ),
        'member2' => "hello, I'm 2",
   );
   ```
3. PHP 5.4+ Shortened array declaration style

   ```
   $object = (object)[
        'member1' => "hello, I'm 1",
        'member1o' => (object)['member1' => "hello, I'm 1o.1"],
        'member2' => "hello, I'm 2",
   ];
   ```

Will both produce exactly the same result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [member1] => hello, I'm 1
    [member1o] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member1] => hello, I'm 1o.1
        )

    [member2] => hello, I'm 2
)
```

nJoy!

Comment: Excellent summary. Good to note the member1o needs to be different from the memeber1 string

Comment: Thanks for the thorough summary. Hopefully, this gets accepted!

Answer (score 6):

You can use :

```
$object = (object)[]; // shorter version of (object)array();

$object->foo = 'bar';
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
function initStdClass($thing) {
    if (is_array($thing)) {
      return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $thing);
    }
    return $thing;
}
```

Comment: Use `__FUNCTION__` for more flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

I use a class I name Dict:

```
class Dict {

    public function __construct($values = array()) {
        foreach($values as $k => $v) {
            $this->{$k} = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

It also has functions for merging with other objects and arrays, but that's kinda out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4):

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3837944/210336) answer to a similar question:

> **As of PHP7**, we have [Anonymous Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) which would allow you to extend a class at runtime, including setting of additional properties:

```
$a = new class() extends MyObject {
    public $property1 = 1;
    public $property2 = 2;
};

echo $a->property1; // prints 1
```

It's not as succinct as the initializer for array. Not sure if I'd use it. But it *is* another option you can consider.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for *deep* conversion is to use `json_encode` + `json_decode` (it decodes to stdClass by default). This way you won't have to repeat `(object)` cast in each nested object.

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode(array(
     'member1' => "hello, I'm 1",
     'member1o' => array(
         'member1' => "hello, I'm 1o.1",
     ),
     'member2' => "hello, I'm 2",
)));
```

output:

```
php > print_r($object);
stdClass Object
(
    [member1] => hello, I'm 1
    [member1o] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member1] => hello, I'm 1o.1
        )

    [member2] => hello, I'm 2
)
```

Comment: But empty arrays are still treated as arrays, though.