# Is there a special object initializer construct in PHP like there is now in C#?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, initialization

I know that in C# you can nowadays do:

```
var a = new MyObject
{
    Property1 = 1,
    Property2 = 2
};
```

Is there something like that in PHP too? Or should I just do it through a constructor or through multiple statements;

```
$a = new MyObject(1, 2);

$a = new MyObject();
$a->property1 = 1;
$a->property2 = 2;
```

If it is possible but everyone thinks it's a terrible idea, I would also like to know.

PS: the object is nothing more than a bunch of properties.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738865/initialize-objects-like-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**As of PHP7**, we have [Anonymous Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) which would allow you to extend a class at runtime, including setting of additional properties:

```
$a = new class() extends MyObject {
    public $property1 = 1;
    public $property2 = 2;
};

echo $a->property1; // prints 1
```

**Before PHP7**, there is no such thing. If the idea is to instantiate the object with arbitrary properties, you can do

```
public function __construct(array $properties)
{
    foreach ($properties as $property => $value) 
    {
        $this->$property = $value
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(array('prop1' => 1, 'prop2' => 2));
```

Add variations as you see fit. For instance, add checks to `property_exists` to only allow setting of defined members. I find throwing random properties at objects a design flaw.

If you do not need a specific class instance, but you just want a random object bag, you can also do

```
$a = (object) [
    'property1' => 1,
    'property2' => 2
];
```

which would then give you an instance of StdClass and which you could access as

```
echo $a->property1; // prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks. The idea was not to instiate aribitrary properties. Thanks anyway for the idea. I'll use my first alternative: A constructor.

Comment: Simple and brilliant, thanks for the inspiration. As for it being a 'design flaw': if a program works, as well as it can be quickly and easily understood by other programmers, then the design is good, no matter what the programming books say.

Comment: @mojuba - Gordon is correct in my opinion. Throwing random properties at objects *is* a design flaw. A lot of PHP is flawed: frankly it's a horrible language that makes it easy for subtle bugs to creep in to your programs (which take ages to track down and fix). The whole point of using classes with defined properties is that it is *not* possible to mess up by mis-typing a property name in code (an IDE will catch it straight away, or a big fat runtime error will occur). Contrast that with accessing an array element that doesn't exist: PHP quietly treats the value as null/empty/whatever.

Comment: @DanielScott it is perfectly possible that you create an object based on data received from JSON, SQL, etc. Many libraries take advantage of this kind of hacks available in dynamic languages (not just PHP btw). Dynamic languages *are* dangerous and error prone anyway, so you can at least learn to use the dynamicity to your advantage.

Comment: @mojuba what's the benefit of populating a class instance with arbitrary properties over using an array or an untyped object?

Comment: @Gordon the user of your library will benefit by having `employee.age` rather than `employee["age"]` in their code. Basically, readability.

Comment: @mojuba but the user will not know that the employee will have an age property. Not if it's a random property slapped on the employee at runtime. That's why you define it as a property of a class and then instantiate the object instead with known properties.

Comment: @Gordon not true. Systems that receive data via JSON or from database servers _kinda_ know the structure but the generic code that decodes e.g. JSON data to native objects does not. This kind of generic libraries can benefit from the hack above big time. Otherwise you will end up with terribly bloated code that redefines de/serialization for each class.

Comment: @mojuba how do they *kinda know the structure*? I am not sure I understand you. Also, I still don't get why you would create a class Employee and dynamically populate it with random public properties over just using a generic/untyped object, such as StdClass for this. If the input data for the Employee does not contain an age property, my code will break unless I check prior to calling employee.age *each time* I want to access this. Also, adding public properties breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @Gordon you don't instantiate an employee object. Let's say you are the user of a library that can de/serialize anything to and from JSON. You define class Employee but you don't need to implement serialization, you just call e.g. `Employee.newFromJSON(jsonData)` and you get an object of the right class with all the properties assigned and ready for use. Now think about how you'd implement a generic `newFromJSON()` if you were to implement such library that doesn't know anything about the user's specific classes. You will realize that it will inevitably involve your hack in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a constructor and set the variables you wish when initialising the object.

Answer (score 2):

I went from c# to PHP too, so I got this working in PHP:

```
$this->candycane = new CandyCane(['Flavor' => 'Peppermint', 'Size' => 'Large']);
```

My objects have a base class that checks to see if there's one argument and if it's an array. If so it calls this:

```
public function LoadFromRow($row){
    foreach ($row as $columnname=>$columnvalue)
        $this->__set($columnname, $columnvalue);
}
```

It also works for loading an object from a database row. Hence the name.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, which is not the proper way but for some cases okay:

```
class Dog
{
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$dogs = [
    1 => (new Dog())->setAge(2)->setName('Max'),
    2 => (new Dog())->setAge(7)->setName('Woofer')
];
```