# Convert an array to a specific object

Tags: php, arrays, object

If I have an array:

[`my_name: 'Xavi', your_name: 'Luis']`

And then I have an Object Name with properties: `myName`, `yourName`.

How could I best convert the array to the specified object?
Is there anything out of the box available, some sort of helper class?

Comment: Worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass/19272096#19272096

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738865/initialize-objects-like-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a duplicate and the answer is not whatever @Alive_to_Die wrote - it sets the array index into exactly named class property, whilst the question is something else...

You will have to manually remap indexes into class properties.

```
class obj
{
    public $myName;
    public $yourName;
}

$array = [
    'my_name' => 'Xavi',
    'your_name' => 'Luis',
    ];

$obj = new obj;
$obj->myName = $array['my_name'];
$obj->yourName = $array['your_name'];

var_dump($obj);
```

Output:

```
object(obj)#1 (2) {
  ["myName"]=>
  string(4) "Xavi"
  ["yourName"]=>
  string(4) "Luis"
}
```

Comment: That mapping is what I amasking for,is there a class i can see that does something similar, so convert underscore to camelcase and then sets the correct properties in an object

Comment: I would not recommend doing any automatic conversion. Either write your own converter or convert manually on the fly. If you use something like `str_replace` or something else, you'd be giving up vast control over your code. And doing things magically is generally a bad idea - harder debugging, harder maintenance, worse delegation ability of the code...